# Escaped characters problem with embed code in Wordpress db

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want the Wordpress admins to be able to change Campaigns, so they would need to store the Embed code from Donatebox in the mySQL db.

I'm using for storing the Data received through the input

```
$contCampaign = htmlspecialchars($_POST["contCampaign"]);
update_option("contCampaign", $contCampaign);
```

And for showing the embed

```
$contCampaignShow = htmlspecialchars_decode(get_option("contCampaign"));
echo $contCampaignShow;
```

But I'm receiving escaped Slashes, so the code doesn't work, this is the generated code in DOM

```
<script src="\&quot;https://donorbox.org/widget.js\&quot;" paypalexpress="\&quot;false\&quot;"></script>
<iframe allowpaymentrequest="\&quot;\&quot;" frameborder="\&quot;0\&quot;" ...
```

Any help please?

Comment: try with `html_entity_decode(get_option("contCampaign"))`

Comment: No luck, I receive the same output :-(

Comment: What would be the purpose of applying `htmlspecialchars` before inserting this into the database? The context here is not HTML, so this is rather nonsense. (Always handle data according to the rules of a context, when you _put_ the data into that context.) What do you get when you don’t apply htmlspecialchars and htmlspecialchars_decode in the first place?

Comment: Without any filtering, it doesn't even let update the db (probably some protection against the injections). with  `esc_attr` it works, but it also escapes the slashes